# Совместить 2 count sql запроса в один YII2

Tags: sql, yii2, select, count

Имеется 2 практически одинаковых запроса:

```
$count_free = $ticket_model->where(['user_id'=>null])->count();
$count_hold = $ticket_model->where(['not',['user_id'=>null]])->count();
```

Обращение идет к одной таблице и к одной колонке user_id. Как сделать так, что бы одним запросом выдавало примерно такое:

```
free hold
0    0
```

Comment: Убрать из WHERE, считать условные агрегаты.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Можете поподробнее.

Comment: В терминах SQL это будет `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN user_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(CASE WHEN user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) FROM tablename`. А перевести в термины фреймворка - это уже без меня.

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать.